# Apache 2.4: Allow access to directory only for ip address range

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-auth, mod-authz-host

I want allow access to `/htdocs/reserved/` directory only for ip addresses from 192.168.1.193 to 192.168.1.254 (.193 --> .254).

I have written this code in `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory /htdocs/reserved/>
    Order Deny, Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.1.193/254
</Directory>
```

After stop, Apache won't restarts and raises this exception:

> The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>   The specified network mask is invalid.

the problem seem the mask `192.168.1.193/254`.

I have also tried:

```
<Directory /htdocs/reserved/>
    Order Deny, Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.1.193 192.168.1.254
</Directory>
```

it works! apache start, but i'm not sure if all ip addresses in the range are allowed to access to directory or only 192.168.1.193 and 192.168.1.254 are allowed.

The official [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html) lacks of clear information (or i'm too stupid to understand it).

The question is: what is the right way for allow a ip address range to access in a directory?

*side note: i have used private range only for example.*

*Thanks at all and sorry for my english.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your netmask is wrong.  The closest you'll be able to do in a single line is 192.168.1.192/26.  Note that that includes the address that ends in 192, not starting at 193.  Otherwise, according to https://ip2cidr.com/, you need

```
192.168.1.193/32
192.168.1.194/31
192.168.1.196/30
192.168.1.200/29
192.168.1.208/28
192.168.1.224/28
192.168.1.240/29
192.168.1.248/30
192.168.1.252/31
192.168.1.254/32
```

Comment: https://ip2cidr.com/ is exactly what i was looking for, thanks !